# Allow templates to be inferred

Tags: c#, .net, generics, type-inference

Say I'm using an [external package for storing graphs](http://quickgraph.codeplex.com/). A BidirectionalGraph takes two templates: a vertex and an edge type:

```
var graph = new BidirectionalGraph<Vertex, Edge<Vertex>>();
```

Unfortunately, this graph package doesn't allow you to get the edges radiating into a vertex in a single line. Instead, you have to provide an `IEnumerable`, which it will populate with the results. This can disrupt a good coding rhythm by making tasks like "loop through all vertices that are successors of vertex `x`" take far too much code.

I wanted to use .NET's extensions to add a one-line solution to the graph class:

```
public static class GraphExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<TEdge> IncomingEdges<TGraphSubtype, TVertex, TEdge>(this TGraphSubtype graph, TVertex n)
        where TGraphSubtype : BidirectionalGraph<TVertex, TEdge>
        where TEdge : IEdge<TVertex>
    {
        IEnumerable<TEdge> inputEdgesForVertex;
        graph.TryGetInEdges(n, out inputEdgesForVertex);
        return inputEdgesForVertex;
    }
}
```

But when I call `graph.IncomingEdges(vertex)`, for some reason C# (.NET version 4.5) can't infer the template arguments, so I have to say:

`graph.IncomingEdges<GraphThatInheritsFromBidirectionalGraph<VertexType,EdgeType>,VertexType,EdgeType>(vertex)`. Not really a great improvement.

**First**, why can't the template types be estimated? I have a feeling it has to do with inheritance, but don't understand. I'm used to using C++, and for some reason feel that gcc could infer the template types.

**Second**, if this can't be prevented, is the correct design choice to make a graph class for actual use, which inherits from BidirectionalGraph? It seems a waste to have to rewrite the constructors, but I'm sure you'd agree that calling the method with explicit template types is inelegant.

**EDIT:**

Strangely, the equivalent specification (below) *does* allow automatic inference of template types. So, even though it solves my initial problem (adding this functionality to the graph), I'd still really like to understand.

```
public static class GraphExtensions
{
        public static IEnumerable<TEdge> IncomingEdges<TVertex, TEdge>(this BidirectionalGraph<TVertex,TEdge> graph, TVertex n)
            where TEdge : IEdge<TVertex>
        {
            IEnumerable<TEdge> inputEdgesForVertex;
            graph.TryGetInEdges(n, out inputEdgesForVertex);
            return inputEdgesForVertex;
        }
}
```

Comment: What is the compiler error? I'm trying to re-produce this without downloading the graphing library.. but so far I am failing :(

Comment: @SimonWhitehead It says "Error 1 'MyDerivedGraph' does not contain a definition for 'IncomingEdges' and no extension method 'IncomingEdges' accepting a first argument of type 'MyDerivedGraph' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)", but when I manually specify the template types, it compiles and runs fine. (EDIT: Resharper suggests inserting <>, trying to help me manually put in templates)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first version of your extension method is able to infer `TGraphType` and `TVertex` but not `TEgde`, as it would require inferring the `TEdge` from the type constraint:

```
where TGraphSubtype : BidirectionalGraph<TVertex, TEdge>
```

which C# compiler does not do (it does not infer generic type parameters from type constraints). I honestly don't know if there is a technical reason behind this or it just wasn't implemented.

Your updated version, on the other hand, includes `BidirectionalGraph<TVertex, TEdge>` as a parameter, so for example when you call the extension method on a class like:

```
class AGraph: BidirectionalGraph<AVertex, AnEdge> { ... }
...
var aGraph = new AGraph();
aGraph.IncomingEdges(vertex);
```

the compiler is able to examine the type `AGraph` and see that there is a unique type `BidirectionalGraph<AVertex, AnEdge>` in its inheritance hierarchy, so it is able to infer `TVertex` and `TEdge`.

Note that if the parameter type were `IGraph<TVertex, TEdge>` (instead of `BidirectionalGraph<TVertex, TEdge>`) and `AGraph` implemented multiple constructed types of that generic interface, e.g.:

```
class AGraph: IGraph<AVertex, AnEdge>, 
              IGraph<AnotherVertex, AnotherEdge> { ... }
```

then type inference would fail once again because it can't tell if, for example, `TVertex` is `AVertex` or `AnotherVertex`.